# Importing data into R, which fileformat is the easiest?

Tags: r

I have a few datasets in the following formats: .asc, .wf1, .xls. I am indifferent about which one I use, as they are exactly the same. Could anyone please tell me which one of the fileformats is easiest to import into R, and how this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save **xls** to txt or csv, they are easiest for R to read:
but be sure that only one header line or no header line is recommended

try

```
    read.table('*.txt', header=T)
    read.table('*.txt', header=F)
    read.delim(*， header=F)
    read.csv("*.csv")
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not `.xls`.  If `.asc` is some sort of fixed-width format, than that can be read in easily with `read.csv` or `read.table`.

Other formats that are easy to read include `CSV` (comma- or tab-separated text files) and `DTA` (Stata files, via `read.dta` in the `foreign` package).

Edit: @KarlOveHufthammer pointed out that `.asc` is most likely a fixed-width format.  In which case `read.fwf` is the tool to use to read it in to R.  Note that FWF is a pain in the heiny to deal with, though, in that you have to have the column widths and names of every column stored somewhere else, then convert that to a format that `read.fwf` can use--and that's before problems like overlapping ranges.

Comment: Just a small comment: If the file is some sort of *fixed width format*, you can use `read.fwf()`, *not* `read.csv()` or `read.table()`, which are for formats where each is field is separated by some character.